# Create bear like div-containers

Tags: html, css, border, border-layout

I am trying to create a website where the main design is inspired from the following image

[image]

I am trying to create three div containers resembling the three bear shapes in the image above. Inside these div containers I am placing my content for the site.

My main problem is adding the head and bottom of the bears, I do not want nor need any content in these parts.

```js
     content = document.getElementById("content");
content.style.paddingTop = content.offsetWidth/2 + "px";
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #00ADEF;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}


#content {
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #F7F3E9;
}
```

```html
    <article id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>
```

My main problem is that I do not know how to append a half circle to the top of a div. Any suggestions?

Comment: try border radius

Comment: border-radius cuts into the div. I want it outside the div.

Comment: add a div above the content area that is the 'head' and another below that becomes the 'bottom'.

Comment: One day, people will learn that HTML and CSS are not graphic drawing tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using pseudo element and some background like this :

```css
body {
margin:0;
background:#f2f2f2;
}

.panda {
  margin: 100px 20px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}


.panda:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20px;
  top: -50px;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  z-index: -100;
}

.panda:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20px;
  top: -50px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
  z-index: -100;
}

.content:before,
.content:after {
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -99;
}

.content:after {
  top: -50px;
  bottom: auto;
}

.eyes:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    top: -15px;
    left: 20px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.eyes:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    top: -15px;
    right: 20px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.pink,
.pink:before,
.pink:after,
.pink .content:before,
.pink .content:after {
  background: pink;
}
.blue,
.blue:before,
.blue:after,
.blue .content:before,
.blue .content:after {
  background: blue;
  color:white;
}

.black {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,white 20%,black 0%, black 50%, white 45%);
  color:red;
}
.black .content:after {
  background: white;
}
.black:before,
.black:after,
.black .content:before{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="panda pink">
  <div class="content">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panda blue">
  <div class="content">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  ipsum lorem ipsum  ipsum lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panda black">
  <span class="eyes"></span>
  <div class="content">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right. Everything is working now. I will clean up these comments.